# Consuming service hosted on glassfish from payara

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, payara

I have a web service hosted on Glassfish Server. I am trying to consume it from the application hosted on Payara. But I am not able to do that(unable to read value). Does Payara Server support the application hosted on glassfish (i use Glassfish 3)? If not, please let me know the reason.

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and ask your question properly.

Comment: "Does Payara Server support the application hosted on glassfish" -> this doesn't make much sense to me. Do you mean you want to use Payara Server to consume a JAX-WS web service? If that is the case then yes, it does. You haven't specified what your problem is, though, so we can't help you with it.

Comment: Hi Mike. I am sorry. I got little confused. We were using Glassfish 3 and recently migrated to Payara. We are able to fetch data through service. For UI we are using ZKoss framework. While binding this data to a combo,  the system shows like 'Unable to read value'. This was working fine when we were using Glassfish. After migration, this is not working at all. I have tried to debug the program from localhost. But no issue i found(Code works as before). Please let me know if you wish to know much details regarding this.